# SumNumbers - coding bat

Tags: java

I'm working [this Codebat problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p121193).

I have seen the solution listed here on the previous sumnumbers question. I have coded

```
if (str.length() == 0) {
    return 0;
}
int sum = 0;
int start = 0;
int stop = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
        start = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j))) {
                stop = j;
                j = j + str.length();
            }
        }
        sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, stop));
    }
}
return sum;
```

I thought this was a simple way to find the start of the number and the end within a string. When I run this on codingbat I get the correct sum (7) for `"5hoco1a1e"` and `"5$$1;;1!!"` Also `"Chocolate"` returns 0 which is OK. In testing when I change the `return` to  `return start;` I get a 5 as the result for the string `"abc123xyz"` (which it should be 123)  All I'm doing (i think) is setting `start` from `i` when I find the first digit within the string. Any thoughts on how I can work though this code? I'm really not looking for the answer, but for someone to let me know where I went astray.

Answer (score 1):

The first flaw is `i` only moves to the next character after the inner loop completes.  When `i` needs to move where to where the inner loop stopped (`i = j` or `i = stop`).  This alone doesn't fix everything.

The next flaw is your code will throw an error if your `String` ends with a number (i.e. `"5hoco1a1e123"`).  Your code will assign `start` a new value once it reaches the last value, but `stop` will not get a new value.  This will cause `sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, stop));` to error since `stop` is less than `start`

Answer (score 0):

After your nested for loop completes, `i` is still the same as it was before the loop started. To fix this, set `i = j` before you end the nested loop:

```
if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j))){
    stop = j;
    i = j;
    j = j+ str.length();
}
```

Comment: Another problem exists after that.

Comment: if (str.length() == 0) return 0;
int sum=0; 
int start = 0;
int stop=0;
  for (int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
       start = i;
       if (i == str.length()-1) stop = i;
       for (int j=i+1;j < str.length()-1;j++){
            if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j))){
               i = j;
               stop = j;
               j = j+ str.length();}
             else {stop = j+1;} 
        }        
   sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start,stop));  
    } 
  } 
 return sum;
}

Comment: on value "aa11b33"  when i = 5,  j should first equal i+1 (6). when I comment out the "sum" line( //sum +=...) and return stop, 4 is returned